# Prove that Ɛ(S) = Ɛ(Ɛ(S))

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

Let M = (Q, Σ, δ, q0, A) be an Ɛ-NFA and let S ⊆ Q

I am having problems starting this question. Would it be reasonable to find a proof for Ɛ(S) = S, and then proving Ɛ(S) = Ɛ(Ɛ(S))? If not, how would you go about doing this proof?

Comment: Could you please give the definition of Ɛ(S) ?

Comment: Ɛ(S) is the same as eclosure(S), just saying we are taking the epsilon closure on the set S ⊆ Q

Comment: Sorry to insist, but this is still not precise enough. Is Ɛ(S) the set of states $q$ such that there exists an Ɛ-path from some state of $S$ to $q$, or the the set of states $q$ such that there exists an Ɛ-path from $q$ to some state of $S$? By the way, giving a precise definition is an important step towards the answer to your question.

Comment: No worries, it is the the set of states q such that there exists an Ɛ-path from q to some state of S

Comment: How would you go about doing it with the other definition? Using the set of states q such that there exists an Ɛ-path from some state of S to q? I may have been confused on the definitions for the question.

Comment: The conclusion would be the same: $Ɛ(S)$ is not equal to $S$ in general, but $Ɛ(Ɛ(S) = Ɛ(S)$.

Comment: See [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/115839/let-m-be-an-epsilon-nfa-and-let-s-subseteq-q-prove-epsilon-s-epsilo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have taken the other definition, but let us work with your definition.
First of all, $Ɛ(S)$ is not necessarily equal to $S$. Take for instance a two-state automaton containing only one Ɛ-transition, namely 
$$
0 \xrightarrow{Ɛ} 1
$$
and let $S = \{1\}$. Then $Ɛ(S) = \{0, 1\}$ since there exists an $Ɛ$-path from $0$ to $1$ and also $Ɛ$-path from $1$ to $1$ (the empty path).

You should be able to prove that $Ɛ(Ɛ(S)) = Ɛ(S)$. **Hint**: the composition of two Ɛ-paths is an Ɛ-path.