# Epsilon Non Deterministic Finite Automata proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, automata, finite-state-machine

1. Let M = (Q, Σ, δ, q0, A) be an ε-NFA and let S ⊆ Q. Prove that ε(S) =
   ε(ε(S)).

I will provide some definitions that may be useful in answering the question

Formal Definition of ε-NFA M = (Q, Σ, δ, q0, A)
with the difference from an NFA in that δ : Q × (Σ ∪ {ε}) → 2^
Q

L(M) = {x ∈ Σ
*
: δ
*
(q0, x) ∩ A ≠ ∅} this is the same definition of L(M) as
per the NFA.
This means that we must consider the ε moves somewhere. And we do this
in the extended transition function.
First we define the ε-closure : ε : 2^Q → 2^
Q

It is defined as follows

1) S ⊆ ε(S)

2) if q ∈ ε(S) then δ(q, ε) ⊆ ε(S)

3) and nothing else is in ε(S)

I have tried answering this but am stuck and could use an explanation.

Comment: Please try to rewrite the OP by using mathjax, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference , this would improve the readability for the community, also making easier for potential answerers to quickly assimilate the text and the point of the question. Own tries should please come with the posted question, since this is often the direction preferred in answers, if the offered starting path can be completed to a valid full answer.

Comment: @dan_fulea ok thanks, I will improve those things for next time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that Ɛ(S) = Ɛ(Ɛ(S))](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3395626/prove-that-%c6%90s-%c6%90%c6%90s)

Answer (score 1):

This is a "short" answer (made long only by building propositions), which is based on a slightly more exact definition of $\epsilon(S)$. This is:

$\epsilon(S)$ is the **minimal** under the possible sets $T$ of states with the properties:

- (1) $T$ contains $S$, and
- (2) starting from $q\in T$ and reading $\epsilon$ we also land in $T$.

Moreover, a state $r^*$ is in $\epsilon(S)$, iff

- (3) $r^*$ can be constructed using a chain with $r_0\in S$
  $$
  r_0\overset\epsilon\to
  r_1\overset\epsilon\to
  r_2\overset\epsilon\to
  \dots
  \overset\epsilon\to
  r_N=r^*\ ,
  $$
  where $N$ is a suitable number of steps. (In fact, all steps in between are
  also in $\epsilon(S)$, but we do not require this, since applying this would mean to show more.)

The notation $q\overset\epsilon\to r$ is a short cut for $r\in\delta(q,\epsilon)$. In words, we land from $q$ in $r$ by eating $\epsilon$ *in a step*. Taking $\epsilon(S)$ means taking the "completion" of this relation, and then by considering the equivalence classes of all elements in $S$. (We are "starting in $S$" and eating $\epsilon$ (nothing) on zero, one, or more steps successively, starting again from the previous landing point. We need the obvious transitivity of this completion below.)

Now we show the wanted equality by double inclusion.

---

**We show** $\epsilon(S) \subseteq \epsilon(\epsilon(S))$. This is clear from the property (1) applied for $S'=\epsilon(S)$ (instead of $S$).

**We show** $\epsilon(S) \supseteq \epsilon(\epsilon(S))$. We start with a state $r^*$ in $\epsilon(\epsilon(S))$. (And want to show it is in the set on the L.H.S. .)
Then this state can be reached by "reading $\epsilon$" in a chain:
$$
r'_0\overset\epsilon\to
r'_1\overset\epsilon\to
r'_2\overset\epsilon\to
\dots
\overset\epsilon\to
r'_N=r^*\ ,
$$
where $r'_0\in\epsilon(S)$. Since $r'_0\in \epsilon(S)$, we can build a chain from some $s_0\in S$ to $r'_0$. And we are done when writing: 
$$
s_0\overset\epsilon\to s_1\overset\epsilon\to s_2\overset\epsilon\to\dots
\overset\epsilon\to s_M=
r'_0\overset\epsilon\to
r'_1\overset\epsilon\to
r'_2\overset\epsilon\to
\dots
\overset\epsilon\to
r'_N=r^*\ .
$$

Comment: its still not clear to me how this proves that ϵ(S) = ϵ(ϵ(S)). How is ϵ(S)⊆ϵ(ϵ(S)) clear from property 1? Are you assuming that S' = ϵ(S)  and T = ϵ(ϵ(S))

Comment: @puj Let $S'$ be $\epsilon(S)$. By definition $S'\subseteq \epsilon(S')$.

Comment: ok that makes sense. I'm still struggling with proving ϵ(S)⊇ϵ(ϵ(S)) using words. I understand your diagrams but can't exactly put it into words